# how to convert last_day format to ddmmyyyy in DB2

Tags: sql, date, db2

i have problem to convert `last_day` data from `yyyymmdd` to `ddmmyyyy`.
my field are integer.so i convert into char. then i try to format into `to_date`. When i try to convert to `ddmmyyyy`.There are show some error message.

```
This is my formula:
LAST_DAY(to_date(cast(IVL_SCHEDULER_PROC_DATE as char(8)),'yyyymmdd'))

Result 
2016-08-18

Expected Result
18-08-2016
```

Anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use varchar_format as below;

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(TO_DATE("IVL_SCHEDULER_PROC_DATE",'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MM-DD-YYYY') from db2inst1.test
18-08-2016
```

this is last_day function with varchar_format;

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE("IVL_SCHEDULER_PROC_DATE",'YYYY-MM-DD')),'MM-DD-YYYY') from db2inst1.test
31-08-2016
```

Comment: yes.it works. but you forgot to convert the field. It should be cast(IVL_SCHEDULER_PROC_DATE as char(8)),'yyyymmdd')

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
select 
  varchar(mod(IVL_SCHEDULER_PROC_DATE,100)) || '-' ||
  varchar(mod(IVL_SCHEDULER_PROC_DATE/100,100)) || '-' ||
  varchar(IVL_SCHEDULER_PROC_DATE/10000)
```

Using a test value of 20151231 I get a '31-12-2015' result.